# How can you turn a generic php library/ libraries into a symfony service to be used in a symfony application?

Tags: php, symfony

I know how to use a bundle in a [symfony project](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), its very easy as shown in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html).
        But suppose I want to create a project which will have the following php projects (which are easy to install via composer) and transform them into services (which are nothing but useful objects) that will be present in the container of my full php project:

1. GitService - using : https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api
2. CronService -using: https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby

I don't have much experience in web development, all I want to do is use these classes for scheduled push and pull from my local machine into github but preferably using the symfony framework, hence I am asking this general project structure level question. Please elaborate your answers if you can.

Thanks

Alam

Update 1: I did find some interesting [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/fabrice.bernhard/modernisation-of-legacy-php-applications) on this kind of topic. They are talking about using the [Facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Here is the summary of their solution :

1. With Symfony, the new API of the Facade Pattern is a service.
2. Create a bundle for every << module >> php you identify.
3. Create a service for each bundle, that will serve as your Facade
   API.
4. ...Now using the Dependency Injection, and Container, you can use these services in a symfony project.

   I feel I had something similar in mind, however I would still like to get opinions on this.

Comment: So you want to create a Bundle that will declare GitService and CronService as Symfony services? Do you want to share this Bundle? Because if you don't want to share it, you can declare the services in your application.

Comment: Yes I am asking how can I do the declaration and set up dependency injection and all. If the bundle is good, I would like to share it. Also I have a use case in my own application, I am building a symfony app that could use the above services in the form of bundle. Or is there a better way ?

Comment: I think you should split this question in 2 questions: How to use a PHP library as a Symfony service? How to create a Symfony Bundle? In fact, you will find some documentation about how to create a Symfony Bundle (or look at any popular bundle to see how it works), so I suggest to keep only the first question.

Comment: About cron, there are already some bundles: https://github.com/michelsalib/BCCCronManagerBundle https://github.com/J-Mose/CommandSchedulerBundle etc.

Comment: Yes. A.L you are right , perhaps I can split the question but I am still learning about all this , to me they seemed very connected , at least from my usage perspective. Once I know how to create services from php libs, then I should be easily create the bundle that has those services , right ? For instance, I use another bundle called https://github.com/Syren7/owncloudApiBundle in my application. It has two services, one for user creation , other for file creation both of which come in my application through the bundle.

Comment: These problems may or not be connected, the fact is: questions with several questions/problems tend to be closed as *too broad* or downvoted. So please keep only one problem per question.

Comment: Ok I have edited the question to reflect your recommendations. Thank you.